# Live USB isn't live, I can only try or install

Tags: 14.04, grub2, usb, live-usb

I've tried about 4 times now to create live (by live I mean I can boot Ubuntu from it (I think, I'm a newbie to this)) Ubuntu usb, to no avail. I want a live usb because my GRUB isn't showing up since I reinstalled windows 7, so I want to go to Ubuntu, and use the terminal to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to create your USB drive so that you can set a **space used to preserve files across reboots**

If you don't know any idea what that is, then you can set 1024 meaning 1 gigabytes for extra space to make room for you to play around.

Long story short, if you have a USB disk more than 2 GBs you can set this 1024. If not, try 100 or some value that can fit into the USB along with the Ubuntu installation (fairly 800 MB sth).

Answer (score 2):

To run a live session choose "Try Ubuntu".  Once it boots into the trial session, then you can access partitions on your hard drives and repair things.

Comment: Some other answers are saying that you need to reserve persistent space for the live OS to work, but I have never found this to be the case. This answer is exactly right. "Try Ubuntu" boots fully and normally into an actual functioning Ubuntu OS from which you can perform whatever operations you wish on your primary boot drive.

Answer (score 0):

When making USB bootable don't forget to set aside separate space for saving files and settings.

Both unetbootin in Windows and USb Creator in Ubuntu allow this, but I think at least 4 gb USb is necessary.
Otherwise you can't save changes in Live USB.